# Navigation fails in IE for flex

Tags: apache-flex

In my application, when I have got an modal window with tab navigation enabled for all the fields. When I am working with chrome, the navigation works fine but when i try it in IE, when i press on tab from the last field, instead of going to the first field, the control goes to the address bar. Does anyone know how to rectify this issue? Is it possible to set next-navigable-item on items?

Answer (score 0):

Look into [tabIndex](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/accessible_6.html).